# Do ApexShare Record counts in Data storage salesforce?

Tags: community

Just want to know, Do ApexShare Record counts in Data storage salesforce?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing records are not counted against the data storage limits.

It is supposed to be part of the data usage for the record that it belongs to (just like field history, approval steps, etc)

For the actual counted size per record, see this article:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193871&language=en_US